# What is the logic in Free groups here

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Free groups have been hurting my brain for months and this one in particular, I cannot comprehend what is going on with logic

> $H= \langle a,b\mid a^{-1}ba=b^2,b^{-1}ab=a^2\rangle$. Show that $H$ is a trivial group. Hint: express $a^{-2}ba^2$ in two different ways to show that $a,b$ commute.

Solution

> Using the first relation, $a^{-2}ba^2=a^{-1}b^2a=(a^{-1}ba)^2=b^4$

Ok, whoa, hold it right there because that doesn't make sense to me.
$a^{-2}ba^2=a^{-1}b^2a$? What, I can concatenate $a^{-1}$ to $a^{-1}b^2a$ and it's still considered "equal"? How? clearly $a^{-2}ba^2 \neq a^{-1}b^2a$.

> Then using the second relation, $a^{-2}ba^2=a^{-2}bb^{-1}ab=a^{-1}b$. Thus $a^{-1}b=b^4$.

I understand this $a^{-2}ba^2=a^{-2}bb^{-1}ab=a^{-1}b$ bit. But I don't understand how $a^{-1}b=b^4$ came about. What, so $a^{-2}ba^2=(a^{-1}ba)^2$?

I really don't understand this, it's like arithmetic but not arithmetic and it's just is hard as anything I could imagine. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start with "$a^{-2} b a^2$".  Remember this because we're going to start the second step with the same thing and whatever we get here will be equal to whatever we get there.

\begin{align}
a^{-2} b a^2 &= a^{-1} a^{-1} b a^1 a^1  \\
  &= a^{-1} (a^{-1} b a^1) a^1  \\
  &= a^{-1} (b^2) a^1  &  &\text{relation in the presentation}  \\
  &= a^{-1} b ()b a^1  \\
  &= a^{-1} b (a a^{-1}) b a^1  &  &\text{because you can always introduce $1$} \\
  &= (a^{-1} b a) (a^{-1} b a^1) \\
  &= (a^{-1} b a)^2 \\
  &= (b^2)^2   &  &\text{relation in the presentation}  \\
  &= b^4  \text{.}
\end{align}
In the second step, we find $a^{-2}ba^2$ is *also* $a^{-1}b$.  So $a^{-1}b = a^{-2}ba^2 = b^4$, using the result of the detailed explanation above.

Answer (score 2):

For the first line:
$$a^{-2}ba^2 = a^{-1}(a^{-1}ba)a = a^{-1}b^2a.$$
For the conclusion, you have shown that
$$a^{-1}b = a^{-2}ba^2 = b^4$$
where in the last equality you used the first line of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

One of the relations you have is that $a^{-1}ba=b^2$, and using that and some clever manipulations you get this (which is just an expanded version of what you wrote):

$$a^{-2}ba^2=a^{-1}(a^{-1}ba)a=a^{-1}b^2a=(a^{-1}ba)^2=(b^2)^2=b^4.$$

The above shows that $a^{-2}ba^2=b^4$, and you understand how $a^{-2}ba^2=a^{-1}b,$ so that means $a^{-1}b=b^4$.